# The differential entropy cannot be negative for pdf in (0,1)

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy

Differential entropy can be negative for some functions, but when the domain is an interval of length $1$, I suspect it can not be.

**Claim.** For any probability density function $f$ with domain $(0,1)$,

$$-\int_0^1 f(x) \log f(x)\ dx \geq 0.$$

Is this claim true?

*Note.* I omitted a minus sign everywhere and the question became misleading. I did not edit this question because that would have affected the accepted answer. Instead, based on this [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31169/should-i-create-a-new-question/31170#31170) recommendation, I wrote [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517995/differential-entropy-cannot-be-positive-for-pdf-in-0-1) clean version for better reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The uniform distribution $U(0,a)$ for any $0<a<1$  has differential entropy $\log(a)$, which is negative.

If you want something that is supported on exactly $(0,1)$, you can consider the average of two independent uniforms on $(0,1)$, which follows a triangular distribution:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
4x & x \in (0, 1/2] \\
4(1-x) & x \in (1/2, 1).\end{cases}$$
The differential entropy is $1/2 + \log(1/2) \approx -0.19.$

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure it's computed correctly? [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integral+of+4*x+log%284*x%29+from+0+to+1%2F2%29%2B%28integral+of+4*%281-x%29+log%284*%281-x%29%29+from+1%2F2+to+1%29) suggests the integral to be 0.193...

Comment: You forgot the negative sign in front of the integral defining differential entropy. Also, note that if $f(x) \geq 0$ on $(0, 1)$, then since $\varphi(x) = x\log x$ is convex for $x > 0$, by Jensen's inequality $\int_0^1 f(x) \log f(x) dx \geqslant \varphi(\int_0^1 f(x) dx) = 0$, so the differential entropy is always non-positive. I just gave an explicit example where it was negative.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot the negative sign everywhere, so my question was actually if it was always non-positive, which you proved shortly in your comment.