# Differential entropy cannot be positive for pdf in (0,1)?

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy

Differential entropy can be non-positive for some functions, but when the domain is an interval of length $1$, I suspect it must be.

**Claim.** For any probability density function $f$ with domain $(0,1)$,

$$-\int_0^1 f(x) \log f(x)\ dx \leq 0.$$

Is this claim true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was originally provided as a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445137/the-differential-entropy-cannot-be-negative-for-pdf-in-0-1#comment7082834_3445240) by user [snar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/24723/snar).

> If $f(x) \geq 0$ on $(0,1)$, then since $\varphi(x)  = x \log x$ is convex for $x>0$, by Jensen's inequality $\int_0^1 \varphi(f(x)) dx
>  \geq \varphi \left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx \right) = 0$, so the differential entropy is always non-positive:
>
> $$-\int_0^1 f(x) \log f(x) dx = -\int_0^1 \varphi(f(x)) dx \leq 0.$$